# get dropdownlist selectedvalue on button click in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have DropDownList and a button in ListView for each row. Now i want to get the selected value of the dropdownlist on Button click event. How can i get this.

Please guide me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `CommandName` property of your buttons, handle the `ItemCommand` event of your listview, and use `FindControl` to find the DropDownList.

For reference, [see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcommand.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`DropDownList.SelectedValue` will get the current selected value.

Comment: Drop down list is in ListView how can i find that on button click on that row?

Comment: FindControl in the listview and use that property.

Comment: How to use FindControl for specified Row?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** on second thoughts, use answer of *TC.*.

---

in the button click event do something like:

```
Button b = (Button)sender;
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)b.Parent.FindControl("DropDownList ID");
string DropDownListSelectedValue = ddl.SelectedValue;
```